# Error #2032 in Xcelsius When "Enable Send"

Tags: xml, cross-domain, xcelsius

My scenario is an Xcelsius dashboard reading data in XML - Flash Variables format generated within an ASP page. Loading data works perfectly fine. However, when I tried to use enable send in order to export data out of Xcelsius, I started to get the error:

```
>An error has occurred.
>For more information, contact the file creator or your system administrator.
>Error: Error #2032
>Connection Type: XML Data
```

Cross-domain file is in place with the right configuration since loading data is okay.

Additionally, I have a "Print" button inside the dashboard, when I try to print in PDF format, I get a "You don't have permission" error when saving the file.